# List available SQL commands at MySQL CLI

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to list available SQL commands at MySQL CLI? I mean if I type `help` at MySQL CLI I see various MySQL CLI specific commands like `clear(\c)` or `tee(\T)`, but it would be handy to see a list of available SQL commands like `SELECT` or `UPDATE` for beginner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
help contents
```

to retrieve a list of the top-level help categories.
If you type:

```
help 'Data Manipulation'
```

Possible result will be:

```
CALL
DELETE
DO
DUAL
HANDLER
INSERT
INSERT DELAYED
INSERT SELECT
JOIN
LOAD DATA
LOAD XML
REPLACE
SELECT
UNION
UPDATE
```

More info you can find:

1. [Server-Side Help](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-side-help-support.html)
2. [HELP Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/help.html)